DUCKDB - WASM Scalar UDF with Utf-8 return type not working as expected
In my project, I am utilizing duckdb wasm. I encountered a need for a custom user-defined function (UDF), so I created one with a return type of UTF-8. However, it consistently returns \u0000.
 // Test udf
    function stringTest(a) {
      try {
        return a + "hello";
      }catch(ex){
        console.log(ex)
      }
    }

    conn.createScalarFunction('stringTest', new arrow.Utf8, stringTest);

Code for element print log
    const result = await conn.query(`SELECT * FROM '${tableName}'`);
        console.log('result: ', result);
        // Get columns and rows
        const columns = result.schema.fields.map(field => field.name);
        let rows = result.toArray();
      
        
        console.log('columns: ', columns);
        
      
        rows.forEach(item => console.log(item));

duckdb - wasm version : 1.28.1-dev294.0
apache-arrow version : 17.0.0
Image of dubugged value in browser

There are many use cases involving string return types. Can you please assist me with this problem?

Can you post the code that caused that error message to be printed to console? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

code added @Dogbert

This seems very similar to the test at https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb-wasm/blob/main/packages/duckdb-wasm/test/udf.test.ts#L150, that is passing on main.
Can you try to check whether that test works for you?
And log duckdb AND apache-arrow versions?

duckdb - wasm version : 1.28.1-dev294.0
apache-arrow version : 17.0.0

test cases also returning same null values
